# How to keep only red builds in jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins

How to keep only the failed builds logs in a job history?

I haven't enough disk space to store both successful and failed builds. I'm looking for a simple way to keep all the red one's logs and none of the blue/green on a Linux jenkins. (Perhaps with a Post-build Action?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Discard Old Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin) plugin can do that for you:

From the link:

[image: After installing this plugin, a new post-build step named 'Discard Old Builds' appears.]

Comment: Last release was in 2013. Here is a newer plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/enhanced-old-build-discarder/