# Prevent jenkins to produce build logs in successful builds

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to prevent jenkins to produce build logs in successful builds. I basically do not need the logs when the build is successful. However I would like to have the builds only in the failure builds.

Thanks

Edit: Please aware that I do not want to remove the builds. Just the logs of them.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235759/how-to-keep-only-red-builds-in-jenkins which points to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin

Comment: but I would like to discard only the logs not the builds. I will keep the builds but delete the logs of them.

Comment: Perhaps not quite what you want but you can gzip the log in the build directory and it will not impact Jenkins, other than the time to uncompress. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2551 It seems a long held wish to manage logs in some way